# How does async await inside a .map work behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, task-queue, array.prototype.map

This is the code that I've written:

```
let aop = [
    'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json',
    'https://datausa.io/api/data?drilldowns=Nation&measures=Population',
    'https://api.publicapis.org/entries'
]; 
        
(async function (){
    Promise.all(aop.map(async url => {
        let response = await fetch(url);
        let json =  await response.json();
        return json;
    })).then(x => console.log(x))
} ());

(function functionThatTakes30SecondsToFinish (){
    // Some heavy lifting tasks
}())
```

I'm getting what I want, but I'm wondering how it's working.

`Promise.all` needs an array of promises, so I used `.map` to do that.

**Now the thing that confuses me** is in the first iteration, for the first url, `fetch` will return a new Promise and then the `await` keyword is encountered. Since the function call has a higher precedence than the `await` keyword, a promise is returned first.

I understand that `await` will throw you one layer outside of your current execution context and then once the promise is resolved, collect the rest of the code and put it into microtask queue for execution.

But if that's the case, our first promise will be returned, and we'll be thrown one layer outside on the global execution context executing the next function, `functionThatTakes30SecondsToFinish()`

Obviously no function takes that long to finish, but just for example's sake, lets pretend.

Once that time consuming function finishes, have we only worked with one URL yet? That too only returned it?

Anyway, let's say 5 seconds later we have our first response back, then `await` will take the code below it:

```
let json =  await response.json();
return json;
```

...and put it into the microtask queue for later execution.

If this works for one URL only, how do we get back into `map` again then?

**Or, this is the second thing that I can assume is happening:**

`map` will go through every url, return the promises and then instead of returning anything into its internal hidden array that's eventually returned, it takes all this code:

```
let json =  await response.json();
return json;
```

... and puts it into the microtask queue for later execution.

So it's like `map` is pausing the callback function for every element.

I am so confused that I can't even ask this properly. Can someone clear this up for me?

Answer (score 1):

The truth is closer to your second description.

When an `async` function gets executed, it *returns* when it encounters an `await` (after evaluating the expression that follows it). The behaviour of `.map` is that after the first callback call has returned, it will execute the callback for the next element, ...etc. Each of those returns when they encounter `await`. All this happens synchronously.

So when `.map` has made all the call backs, it returns an array with the results. In this case the results are all promises.

`Promise.all` is then executed, which creates yet another promise. The `then` method is executed on it, but not yet its callback.

Then the "heavy lifting" code executes.

Once that has finished, and the call stack is empty, the promise job queue is monitored. For the `fetch` calls who got a response back, there will be a job in that queue. It could even be 3 jobs, if in that busy period the HTTP responses arrived for all three requests.

These job(s) correspond to resolved promises that have an `await` going with it. The execution context of the function that has that `await` will be restored, and execution continues, ...etc. If there is nothing more to execute, the next job from that queue will be processed, leading to a similar scenario, ...etc.

As there are more `awaits` (going with the `.json()` calls), the function will return again, this time making the call stack empty, which will again result in a promise job being added to the queue (when `.json()` has done its job).

When all these `await`-ed promises have resolved, and all code after it has been executed, the promises that were passed to `Promise.all` will resolve. This will in turn resolve the promise created by `Promise.all`, and so the chained `then` callback will execute.

Comment: This makes a bit more sense, thanks for the reply! 

I think the callback will run on each element, and then, a/c to my narrowed knowledge, I think the functionThatTakes30SecondsToFinish() will run because our fetches still havent been resolved. 

At 30 sec lets say, its resolved then the rest of the code is put into the microtask queue for later execution and then .json() and other code will be executed and finally that'll be returned to the internal .map array which will be returned to Promise.all() eventually!

I think I need to practice more! :)

Comment: *"I think the callback will run on each element,"*: it does. *"then, I think the functionThatTakes30SecondsToFinish() will run"*: but first `Promise.all` will execute, and the `then` method will execute, registering the callback for later execution. *"the rest of the code is put into the microtask queue"*: no, code is not put in the queue. It is a job, a kind of function call. *"that'll be returned to the internal .map array"*: no, the mapped array is already created, and has promise objects. The only thing that happens there, is that those promises move to a resolved state.